# Defined bean to take enum construtor-arg

Tags: spring, enums

A connection pool class used for all the data source connections. It has a static enum to indicate type of connection.

```
class ConnectionPool {

   public static enum Type {
     t1,
     t2,
     t3;
   }
…
}
```

Another class does not have default contractor, the constructor takes the Type as contractor argument

```
class Update {
   public Update(Type type) {
      this.type = type;
   }
...
}
```

In applicationContext.xml, defined a bean

```
<bean id="update" class="package.Update">
    <contructor-arg type="package.ConnectionPool.Type">
        <value>Type.t1</value>
    </contructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But I got

```
Error creating bean with name 'update' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [package.ConnectionPools$PoolType]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
<bean id="update" class="package.Update">
    <constructor-arg type="package.ConnectionPool.Type">
        <value>t1</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

or even:

```
<bean id="update" class="package.Update">
    <constructor-arg type="package.ConnectionPool.Type" value="t1"/>
</bean>
```

or my favorite:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Update update() {
        return new Update(t1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, Tomasz I should put more in my original question that I tried <value>t1</value> too, it didn't work either

Comment: IntelliJ .. "picks up" on the auto-sense for the values of the ENUM too.  Aka, in my situation, when I started typing the "t1", IntelliJ auto-sense "presented" all the values of the Enum.  Thanks T.N.